# What does it really mean to fix a conditional probability distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I've encountered the following statement:

> Let $(X,Y) \sim p(x, y) = p(x)p(y|x)$
>
> Fix a conditional probability distribution $p(y|x)$. Then, $p(y)$ is a
> linear function of $p(x)$.

I can't really understand what this means. Do we pick a $X=x$ and then given that a $Y=y$ afterwards ? That seems to me that it makes $p(y|x)$ just a constant after selections. Then how come $p(y)$ becomes linear function of $p(x)$ ?

Comment: They're saying, "If we first assume that the conditional probability distribution, $p(y|x)$, exists, then…" As for the rest, how is the joint distribution, $p(x,y)$ related to the conditional distributions and marginal distributions?

Comment: @SeanLake Edited. I guess we sum both sides over x to get the relation between them ?

Comment: Not quite. Try integrating both sides of the equation with respect to $x$. Doing so over $y$ will just get $p(x) = p(x)$.

Comment: And that tells us what exactly ? There's no need to do anything to tell $p(x) = p(x)$. Don't I need somehow to show $p(y) = ap(x)$ for some a ?

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed.

Comment: So, summing over $x$ gives $p(y)$ on LHS. However, I'm still not sure how to treat $p(y|x)$. If I think it just a constant, say $a$ then I get $a$ on RHS. Hence, $p(y) = a$. This doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47088/discussion-between-spiderrico-and-sean-lake).

Comment: If the conditional probability is fixed, the linearity of the transformation $p_X\to p_Y$ is clear: For each $y$, $p_Y(y)$ depends linearly on $p_X=(p_X(x))_x$ since $p_Y(y)=L_y(p_X)$ where $L_y$ is the linear function defined by $L_y(a)=\sum\limits_xp(y\mid x)a_x$ for every vector $a=(a_x)_x$.